# Regex to convert text URLs in Markdown to Links

Tags: node.js, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to convert text Links (with a FQDN i.e. no relative links) in markdown text to Markdown links. It is working fine except when the source markdown has already converted the text to links. For example this is the source text:

```
Login in to My site [https://example.com/](https://example.com/) and select Something > Select below details further.
(https://example.com/abc/1.html)

Also have a look at https://example.com/abc/1.html
```

My regex: `/(?<!\]\()(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim`.

Expected: match only the second and third link. Current outcome: matches 3 URLs.

I tried adding a negative lookahead at the end, similar to the negative lookbehind at the beginning but that just omits the last character of the URL which is a bummer!

I'm using this in NodeJS.

Here's a link to the [regex101 with the sample data](https://regex101.com/r/nu7nf8/3)

Comment: The square bracket in the negative lookbehind of your expression is in the wrong direction

Comment: @Tranbi thanks for this, I need the square brackets in both directions. After adding that, it seems to be working as expected. Here's the regex for reference `(?<!(\]\(|\[))(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])(?!\]\()`

Comment: I thought you intended to write `(?<!\[|\()` but what you're doing is more robust since you'll get links between parenthesis if they're not preceded by `]`. (I didn't check the rest of the expression) Glad I could be of any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pattern to match what you do not want, and capture what you do want in group 1.

You can make use of the callback function of [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) in the replacement.

You can check id group 1 exists. If it does, replace with you custom replacement. If it does not exist, replace with the full match

```
\[(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[^\]\[]+\]\([^()]*\)|((?:https?|ftp):\/\/\S+)
```

In parts the pattern matches:

- `\[` Match`[`
- `(?:https?|ftp):\/\/` Match one of the protocols and `://`
- `[^\]\[]+` Match 1+ times any char except `[` and `]`
- `\]` Match `]`
- `\([^()]*\)` Match from `(` till `)`
- `|` Or
- `((?:https?|ftp):\/\/\S+)` Capture in **group 1** a url like format

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FfKkTM/1)

To not match parenthesis in the url:

```
\[(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[^\]\[]+\]\([^()]*\)|((?:https?|ftp):\/\/[^()\s]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vvsaBw/1)

Or specifically capture a url between parenthesis:

```
\[(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[^\]\[]+\]\([^()]*\)|\(((?:https?|ftp):\/\/\S+)\)|((?:https?|ftp):\/\/[^()\s]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JZ0XjM/1)

Comment: I like this approach! I'm trying out how it behaves in the replace/substitution time. Have added another case where this is currently failing. `(https://example.com/)`

Comment: @Birla, if you don't want to match the closing parenthesis `/\[(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[^\]\[]+\]\([^()]*\)|((?:https?|ftp):\/\/[^()\s]+)/gi`  see https://regex101.com/r/vvsaBw/1

Comment: @Birla You could also capture the url between parenthesis in a separate group `/\[(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[^\]\[]+\]\([^()]*\)|\(((?:https?|ftp):\/\/\S+)\)|((?:https?|ftp):\/\/[^()\s]+)/gi` See https://regex101.com/r/JZ0XjM/1

Answer (score 3):

You may choose to not specify a lookahead/lookbehind by simply not matching if the character before `"http"` is an opening bracket:

```
[^\[\(](https?|ftp):\/\/[^\s]*
```

But then if you strictly want to exclude all URLs in the format `[x](y)` then use this:

```
(?<!\]\()((?:https?|ftp):\/\/[^\s\]\)]*)(?:[\s\]\)](?!\()|$)
```

[image]

Where:

- `(?<!\]\()` - Lookbehind assertion to ensure the this is not the `y` in `[x](y)`
- `(` - Capture URL part

  - `(?:https?|ftp):\/\/` - Match the http/ftp part of the URL
  - `[^\s\]\)]*` - Match the remaining part of the URL.
- `)` - End of capturing of URL
- `(?:` - Non-capturing group

  - `[\s\]\)]` - Match either a space character, closing bracket, or closing parenthesis. The reason we need to match the closing bracket/parenthesis is to allow URLs in the format e.g. `(Check https://google.com)` or `[Check https://google.com]`
  - `(?!\()` - Lookahead assertion to ensure the this is not the `x` in `[x](y)`
  - `|` - Or
  - `$` - End of String
- `)` - End of non-capturing group

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have added another case where it should match to the original URL. `(https://example.com/)`

Comment: @Birla I updated my answer. It is stricter thus is more correct than my initial answer. I believe it also conforms to your updated requirements.